# ValueError in Django when trying to edit and .save() IP addresses

Tags: python, django

Error received:

```
Exception Type: ValueError at /institutes_admin/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Full traceback at:  http://www.pastie.org/1307821

Comment: 0% acceptance will get no/few answers

Comment: Can you please give the model and view (or your `admin.py`, seems like this is an `admin.py` issue)?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you updated an instance variable on your model which should be an integer but cannot be type cast to an integer correctly.